# Android how to fill parent but leave some space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

The title isn't good but i didn't know how else to describe

I have a `relative layout` with 2 elements, some container and a button at bottom.

I want the container fill all the space in the relativelayout leaving just the space enough to put the button

here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout  //i'm using linearlayout as an example, it could be anything here
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

here is how i want it look like

The red means the relavitive layout, the green the linear layout, and the yellow means the button...

[image]

how can i make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:padding="5dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/b"
        android:background="@color/green">

    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="this is the button"
        android:background="@color/yellow"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you something close to what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout  //i'm using linearlayout as an example, it could be anything here
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:text="asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd" />

</LinearLayout>
```